# Leave preferred applications loaded on RAM on Windows

Tags: windows, ram

Is it possible to leave some applications running on RAM after closing them on Windows. What Im askig is like cached RAM but more like application specific, to specifically run those applications faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows does that automatically with its [SuperFetch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Vista_I/O_technologies#SuperFetch) subsystem. It monitors which applications are used frequently and at what time of day and makes sure to have them cached at the right time.

And generally, when closing an application its files should still be cached, so a subsequent startup should be fast.